# reproduce GIF-like image in canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I need an image that is drawn in html5 canvas to look like a gif image (make it have 256 colors only). Is there any function that makes canvas have only 256 or less colors and make it convert images that are placed into it have only 256 or less colors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is such a method in the 2D context of the canvas.

However, it does not seem to be very complicate. 256 colors = 8 levels of red, green and blue.
So you can convert the image to respect this rule.

To achieve this, you need to change the color of each pixels.
Whad I'd do is to create a temporary canvas to manipulate the image, something like this (not tested):

```
//create copy of the image in a temporary context
        this.tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.tmpCanvas.width = myIMage.width;
        this.tmpCanvas.height = myIMage.height;
        var scaledContext = this.tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
        scaledContext.drawImage(myIMage, 0, 0, myIMage.width, myIMage.height, 0, 0, myIMage.width, myIMage.height);

        //get image data
        imageData = scaledContext.getImageData(0, 0, myIMage.width, myIMage.height);

        //loop over copied image date and modifiy pixels value
        for(var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i += 4) { // 4 because RGBA
            //red component
            imageData[i] = Math.round(imageData[i] / 64);
            //green component
            imageData[i + 1] = Math.round(imageData[i+1] / 64);
            //blue component
            imageData[i + 2] = Math.round(imageData[i+2] / 64);
        }

        scaledContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

I didn't test this code, but the idea is there

Comment: Nope - this one didn't work. and well - it shouldn't. It will simply leave all colors from 1-3 and just darken the image. any other solutions?

Comment: Yep, by reading what I wrote, I understand my mistake. The aim is not to divide the three channels by 64 but to only use 8 colors between the 256, someting like that (but need to be re-formatted) : `if r<16 then r=0 else if r<48 then r=32 else if r <80 then r = 64 else if r<112 then r=96 else if r<144 then r=128 ...`